# view parameters passed to JavaScript function in Chrome

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, timeline

I'm using Timeline in Chrome Developer Tools to help write a userscript. The timeline shows which functions are called, but not what values are actually passed to the parameters:

[image]

Is there a way to view the actual function that was run, including its values? I'm looking for any solution that will help me do this, even outside of Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Chromium does not list function `arguments` with the other function parameters, or in any of the closure sections.

The arguments passed to a function are placed into a local property called `arguments`.  This property is an `array`.

There are 2 ways to view them at a breakpoint.

## In The Console

Open the console, and type `arguments`.  Then press `enter`.

[image]

## In The Watch Panel

Open the `watch panel` in the debugger, and enter `arguments` as a watch item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open `Sources` tab at `DevTools`, select `Snippets` tab at left, right-click and select `New`, place text of function in middle window, return `arguments` from defined function, select text of function in middle window, right-click and select `Add to Watch` . At right window at `Watch Expressions` selected named function should be listed on left followed by how function is called, e.g., `fn("abc", "def")` followed by `: Arguments[n]` indicating and listing `arguments` passed to function where `n` is number of `arguments` passed; e.g., `Arguments[2]` for `fn("abc", "def")`

Comment: could you please add some screenshots to illustrate your answer?

Comment: @gen Is the procedure at Answer not described adequately?

Comment: I believe so. I'm confused about what the _text of function_ is supposed to be. If you could attach a screenshot for that step, or explain it a bit further, that would make your answer much more accessible.

Comment: I agree with @gen. Your answer is not clear at all.