# Get javascript variables via developer tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, developer-tools

I was wondering if it's possible to get the variables I used in my files via developer tools (in chrome, safari or firefox).

For example, if I have declare a variable 'test-1' in a file 'file-1.js' I want to get that varibale via developer tools.

**EDIT**

And if it's possible to block it

Comment: If variable is global, you can access that from console

Comment: You can only if is a global variable

Comment: And how is the command to access it?

Comment: Use `debugger;` in the `function` to access local variable of the `function`

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086894/view-parameters-passed-to-javascript-function-in-chrome

Comment: I don't understand what you want to get. but if you want variables' values from a js file in chrome, right-click -> inspect, then select "sources". There you see all loaded js file. you can even have breakpoint there and debug each value changes too.

Comment: In chrome if you go to sources off to the side is the debugger that allows you to pause script execution run it one line at a time and view the variables in that scope

Answer (score 0):

> Use `debugger` to get the variable value in the console.

Try this:

```js
(function() {
  var a = 100;
  debugger; //write a in conseole and you will get 100

  function test() {
    var b = 200;
    debugger;
    //write b in conseole and you will get 200
  }
  test();
})()
```

To resume script execution press <kbd>f8</kbd>

To step over next function call press <kbd>f10</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can set the variable to be watched in the browser debugger. You could also set a breakpoint on the function and then step through the many properties and variables of that function.

Here is how to do it in Fire Fox.

[Examine, modify, and watch variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Examine,_modify,_and_watch_variables)